# Is String.find() faster than O(N) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, subsequence

There's a question on leetcode which goes as follows:

Given strings s1 and s2, return the minimum contiguous substring part of s1, so that s2 is a subsequence of the part.
If there is no such window in s1 that covers all characters in s2, return the empty string "". If there are multiple such minimum-length windows, return the one with the left-most starting index.

My proposed solution was:

```
def minWindow(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
    if len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
        return ""
    recordKeeper = []

    minLengthSubsequence = float('inf')
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] == s2[0]:
            t = time.time()
            matchLength = self.matchMinSubsequence(s1[i + 1:], s2[1:])
            print(time.time() - t)
            if matchLength == float('inf'):
                continue
            recordKeeper.append((i, matchLength + 1))
            minLengthSubsequence = min(minLengthSubsequence, matchLength + 1)

    for i in recordKeeper:
        if i[1] == minLengthSubsequence:
            return s1[i[0]:i[0] + i[1]]
    return ""

# Searches if s2 is a subsequence of s1 and returns the minimum length which can make it a subsequence or returns inf otherwise.
def matchMinSubsequence(self, s1, s2):
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return 0
    target = s2[0]

    # search for the next match
    searchResult = -1
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] == target:
            searchResult = i
            break

    if searchResult is not -1:
        return searchResult + 1 + self.matchMinSubsequence(s1[searchResult+1:], s2[1:])

    return float('inf')
```

This TLEs. **However**, if I make a small change to the `matchMinSubsequence` function and search for the next match using `searchResult = s1.find(target)`. The solution gets accepted by a good margin. The function becomes as follows after the change:

```
    def matchMinSubsequence(self, s1, s2):
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return 0

    target = s2[0]

    searchResult = s1.find(target)
    if searchResult is not -1:
        return searchResult + 1 + self.matchMinSubsequence(s1[searchResult+1:], s2[1:])

    return float('inf')
```

My Question then is:
Finding a first occurrence of a character in a string is an O(N) operation. What does s1.find() do so it becomes as fast as 100x. I have checked the time taken is of order 10^-3 for manual search and 10^-5 for s1.find.

The string is not ordered or sorted that we could use any b-search. The only O(1) algo is to create a map which in itself takes O(N) to construct.
I am confused...

Comment: I'd expect that it's still O(n), but there's a constant-factor improvement having it done in C rather than through the Python interpreter.

Comment: The C implementation is likely optimized for your architecture as well. The answer is in the overhead of python loops.

Comment: In worst case it takes O(n), it is performing better may be because it searches for first occurrence of target in original string and stop finding afterwards.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi It's the reverse. The find function is faster.

Comment: @Samwise
Do you mean that the because find function is written in c underneath(I am assuming here), it's running faster. Otherwise the two are same. Both O(N).

Comment: Yes.  Both being O(n) doesn't mean that both are exactly equally fast, it just means that both scale linearly with the length of the string in the worst case (i.e. where the match is at the very end of the string).